# record .wav format file in android using OmRecorder

Tags: android, voice-recording

So i'm trying to record an audio for users and trying to delete the silence when the user dont speak.

For that measure i searched a lot i found out that you can do the record with media recorder or audio recorder and then convert it and try to analyze chunks for detecting silence.

Well that too much work for someone that just started working with android, then i found this project that is already working and you can use it as a dependency you just need to adapt to your case.

this is the link : https://github.com/kailash09dabhi/OmRecorder

Now my question is whenever i try to run my application when i hit the imageview that suppose to launch the recording step the application crash and it close automatically, and i get this error : 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: could not build OutputStream from this file test.wav

Can anyone suggest any solution ??

Manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.authentric.audioenrol">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

mainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Recorder recorder;
ImageView recordButton;
CheckBox skipSilence;
private Button pauseResumeButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Wav Recorder");
    setupRecorder();
    skipSilence = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.skipSilence);
    skipSilence.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                setupNoiseRecorder();
            } else {
                setupRecorder();
            }
        }
    });
    recordButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
    recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            recorder.startRecording();
            skipSilence.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.stopButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                recorder.stopRecording();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            skipSilence.setEnabled(true);
            recordButton.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    animateVoice(0);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    pauseResumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseResumeButton);
    pauseResumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean isPaused = false;

        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            if (recorder == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please start recording first!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (!isPaused) {
                pauseResumeButton.setText(getString(R.string.resume_recording));
                recorder.pauseRecording();
                pauseResumeButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        animateVoice(0);
                    }
                }, 100);
            } else {
                pauseResumeButton.setText(getString(R.string.pause_recording));
                recorder.resumeRecording();
            }
            isPaused = !isPaused;
        }
    });
}

private void setupRecorder() {
    recorder = OmRecorder.wav(
            new PullTransport.Default(mic(), new PullTransport.OnAudioChunkPulledListener() {
                @Override public void onAudioChunkPulled(AudioChunk audioChunk) {
                    animateVoice((float) (audioChunk.maxAmplitude() / 200.0));
                }
            }), file());
}

private void setupNoiseRecorder() {
    recorder = OmRecorder.wav(
            new PullTransport.Noise(mic(),
                    new PullTransport.OnAudioChunkPulledListener() {
                        @Override public void onAudioChunkPulled(AudioChunk audioChunk) {
                            animateVoice((float) (audioChunk.maxAmplitude() / 200.0));
                        }
                    },
                    new WriteAction.Default(),
                    new Recorder.OnSilenceListener() {
                        @Override public void onSilence(long silenceTime) {
                            Log.e("silenceTime", String.valueOf(silenceTime));
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "silence of " + silenceTime + " detected",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, 200
            ), file()
    );
}

private void animateVoice(final float maxPeak) {
    recordButton.animate().scaleX(1 + maxPeak).scaleY(1 + maxPeak).setDuration(10).start();
}

private PullableSource mic() {
    return new PullableSource.Default(
            new AudioRecordConfig.Default(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, 44100
            )
    );
}

@NonNull private File file() {
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.wav");
}
}
```

activityMain.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="00:00:00"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="55sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="click microphone to record"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseResumeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/pause_recording"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/recordButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_microphone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stopButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_stop"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/skipSilence"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="skip silence"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the provided code, the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not requested at runtime. It could cause the  aforementioned RuntimeException on Android 6+:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not build OutputStream from this file test.wav
    at omrecorder.AbstractRecorder.outputStream(AbstractRecorder.java:67)
    at omrecorder.AbstractRecorder.startRecording(AbstractRecorder.java:54)
    at ...
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test.wav (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at omrecorder.AbstractRecorder.outputStream(AbstractRecorder.java:64)
    at omrecorder.AbstractRecorder.startRecording(AbstractRecorder.java:54) 
    at ...
```

Starting from Android 6 (API 23), the dangerous permissions (including WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) must be [requested at runtime](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous-permission-prompt), in addition to the AndroidManifest.xml declaration.

The following code fragment checks if permission is granted, otherwise requests it:

```
// ID to identify permission request
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID = 1;

// Check if permission is granted
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
             thisActivity,
             new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
             MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID);
} else {
    // already granted, start OmRecorder
}

// Override in Activity to check the request result
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // granted, start OmRecorder
            } 
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

See more detailed documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).